# What is the correct way to make a custom method that converts string to array and returns? c#

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble making a working function to convert a string to an array, and return the function to the main method in C#. Here's my code. What am I doing wrong? My current return isn't showing in my main method.

```
//ask user to give a list of items separated by comments.
Console.WriteLine("Today we will be creating a shopping list.\n\rPlease enter a list of items separated by commas.");

//variable to catch user response
string userList = Console.ReadLine();

//validate user input
if (userList.Contains(","))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for the list, we will now ask you for the cost of each item");
}
else
{
    while (!(userList.Contains(",")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your list is either blank or contains no commas. Please enter a list of items seperated by commas.");
        userList = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static string[] TextToArray(string use)
{
    string[] itemList = use.Split(',');
    return itemList;
}
```

Comment: You may want to specify in your question title that you want a string array, not just any array.   I was about to offer `use.ToCharArray()`.

Comment: Your logic to check for a "comma" seems odd... what if the user only typed one (1) item?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the method. Either

```
string[] shoppingItems = TextToArray(userList);
```

Or

```
string[] shoppingItems = userList.Split(',')
```

Also: Think about what happens if the user wants to add only a single item to the shopping list.

Comment: When i go to call the method, the return "itemList" doesn't show in my main method. I've tried using the TextToArray and it prints out "system.string[]"

Comment: Yes, it will print "System.String[]" if you use `Console.WriteLine(shoppingItems)`. Try `Console.WriteLine(shoppingItems[0])` or `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-and-", shoppingItems))`

Answer (score 0):

The method String.Split takes an array of Strings or Chars. See doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can rewrite your code:

```
string[] itemList = use.Split(new char[]{','});
```

Comment: I tried rewriting to what you suggested, but when i go to call the function in my main method, "itemList" isn't seen. Is there anything else i should be checking?

Comment: @ColeMader Where do you call the method TextToArray? I don't see the call in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check your code in vs right now so I don't see mistake for now. However you are asking what is the proper way then I suggest to use extension method to achieve your goal. It will be more elegant in my opinion

Check second example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/bb383977(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't covered in the class, and we are only able to use what was covered on this project, even if other ways make more sense lol. I'm not getting any errors, but for some reason the return "itemList" isn't showing in my main method

Comment: Hmm...is that "static" necesarry?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to keep it simple as this looks like a homework assignment, the solution below may help. It is unnecessary to check if the user input contains a comma “,”. Simply check for an empty string then indicate to the user that there are no items. If the user types something then simply split on commas “,” removing empty strings if the user typed “, ,” or “,  ,“. Then loop through the list and trim off any extra spaces in front and end of the string, then return the string array. Hope this helps.

```
private static string[] GetGroceryList() {
  Console.WriteLine("Today we will be creating a shopping list.\n\rPlease enter a list of items separated by commas.");
  string userList = Console.ReadLine();
  if (userList != "") {
    string[] userArray = userList.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i < userArray.Length; i++) {
      userArray[i] = userArray[i].Trim();
    }
    return userArray;
  }
  else {
    return new string[0];
  }
}
```

Then to use the above method…

```
string[] items = GetGroceryList();
if (items.Length > 0) {
  Console.WriteLine("Thanks for the list, we will now ask you for the cost of each item");
  foreach (string item in items) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    // get the cost of the item????
  }
}
else {
  Console.WriteLine("Your list is blank");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```